# Get percentage with ddply function

Tags: r, plyr

I want to divide the percent into Korea and Taiwan separately.
I don't have any idea to calculate the percent with `ddply` fucntion separately.

```
plot<-ddply(
    data, 
    c("Country", "Here.is.usually.much.garbage.distributed."),
    summarise,
    n=length(Here.is.usually.much.garbage.distributed.),
    percent=((n/sum(plot$n))*100)
)
```

Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

> plot
>     [image]

Comment: Please make your question more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Unrelated but please avoid names like `plot`(although `df` is also commonly used :))

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching to `dplyr` instead of `plyr`. Try using :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(Country, `Here.is.usually.much.garbage.distributed.`) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(N = .N), by = .(Country, `Here.is.usually.much.garbage.distributed.`)][,
         percent := N/sum(N) * 100][]
```

---

With `ddply`, we get the count and do the percent outside

```
library(plyr)
out <-ddply(
        data, 
           c("Country", "Here.is.usually.much.garbage.distributed."),
         summarise,
n=length(`Here.is.usually.much.garbage.distributed.`)
 )
out$perc <- out$n/sum(out$n) * 100
```